# PHP: How to read the current date/time from the server, not from php.ini

Tags: php, datetime

Here is my problem:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime());  

echo exec('date');
```

The output is:

```
2012-03-21 08:45:51
2012-03-21 08:45:51

Wed Mar 21 10:45:51 EDT 2012
```

Server time is off 2 hours from the time returned by php date(); or any other php date/time function. It happens because server time set to EST and PHP.INI date.timezone="America/Denver"

I need to synchronize those two, by using date_default_timezone_set, but I don't know in advance what is the difference.

Is there any other way to get local server time besides calling exec?

UPD: I know that php.ini setting is wrong and that I can change it. The problem is that this script will work on nobody knows what kind of servers. I can't go to each and every one of them and correct the php.ini file. I also don't know in advance what timezone will be on those servers. I need a dynamic solution that will work everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the  ini date time zone and print the date

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: I agree, it sounds like the issue is just that your `php.ini` is misconfigured. Change your configuration file to be accurate and you should be fine.

Comment: I know that, the problem is that this script will work on nobody know what kind of servers. I can't go to each and every one of them and correct the php.ini files. I need a dynamic solution that will work everywhere.

Comment: you dont have to correct ini file. this  you have to put in the top of the script

Answer (score 2):

```
Change value of date.timezone from php.ini [Date] and restart your server.
You can get your date.timezone value form-
http://au.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php


For Bangladesh I set in my php.ini [Date]
date.timezone = Asia/Dhaka


You get your php.ini in C:\xampp\php address for XAMP server and Windows.
```

Answer (score 0):

OR
some hosts give you possibility to edit `php.ini`
look for `php config` in `cpanel`

Comment: This will be deployed on thousands different servers, I can't go to all of them and change php.ini. I need a dynamic solution that will work everywhere.

Comment: so store it in TIMESTAMP then and convert for each user directly

Answer (score 0):

On *nix, you can use formatting parameters to `date` to get what you need:

- `date +%z` — timezone (hhmm)
- `date +%:z` — timezone (hh:mm)
- `date +%Z` — timezone abbreviation (e.g. "EDT")

Making a system call (e.g. `echo exec('date +%z');`) will bypass any INI settings as per [date_default_timezone_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php). Note that this function issues an E_WARNING if it reads from the system time, and indeed from PHP 5.4 it doesn't even allow reading from it — specifically because it can't be relied upon.

To be consistent, regardless of the server settings you should use UTC within your application. For ease of use, GMT is close enough to UTC for most purposes, so you can use `gmdate()`.